# I have six Samsung Galaxy Avants that I can't do much with

Tags: samsung

The owner of my company upgraded our employee phones to something more current. He was going to literally just throw away six perfect condition Galaxy Avants with cases and chargers until I asked if I could have them since they were trash to him. He said sure.

So here I am, stuck because the company software is still on here. I can't really delete because I need admin permission and the application that we used is actually no longer in service (our admin and her team built a new app for the new phones)

I don't really know how to word this, because I have not really been in this situation before...But how can I get these phones back to factory settings? I have the passwords to get into the UI like you would normally but it's still recognizing that it is a phone for my company, with the no longer working app, and no ability really to navigate the phone because it wants me inside of this app.

Thank you in advanced, sorry to be vague.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to restore factory settings by flashing the Samsung stock ROM using the official Samsung tool named Kies. The procedure is explained [here](https://youtu.be/LqoX7wNhotk). Your device name should be Samsung Galaxy Avant G386T.

Alternatively you can try Odin. The procedure is explained [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/restore-stock-rom-for-samsung-devices-android/). You must be aware that Odin is not supported by Samsung. Using it incorrectly or flashing an incorrect ROM (for instance a ROM intended for another device) can brick (permanently damage) your phone.

Comment: 10 months later I finally got around to actually doing this and I'm having difficulty. When I attempt with kies, nothing happens. it gets to 100% and that window closes. then nothing else happens and I'm back to square one. any thoughts? thank you

Comment: Is there any log file from Kies you can post here?

Comment: And did you have any success with your attempt to factory reset your phones?